# Does std::thread run before I call join()?

Tags: c++, multithreading

After I instantiate the `std::thread` does it start running then? Or does a thread only start running when I call `join()`? This is a bit unclear in the docs.

Comment: It starts running immediately. It would rather pointless for a new thread to wait until some other thread wants to join it, before it does anything.

Comment: Threads are created in a running state, so the thread will execute before the `join()` call. And anticipating your next question, perhaps, there is no option to create a thread in a stopped state, although you could use a `std::mutex` or the like to pause threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will execute when you instantiate it.

Joining is used so that the current thread will wait until your other thread finishes execution.

Some example code from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

```
    void f1(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Thread 1 executing\n";
        ++n;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}

void f2(int& n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Thread 2 executing\n";
        ++n;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    std::thread t1; // t1 is not a thread
    std::thread t2(f1, n + 1); // pass by value
    std::thread t3(f2, std::ref(n)); // pass by reference
    std::thread t4(std::move(t3)); // t4 is now running f2(). t3 is no longer a thread
    t2.join();
    t4.join();
    std::cout << "Final value of n is " << n << '\n';
}

    Possible output:
Thread 1 executing
Thread 2 executing
Thread 1 executing
Thread 2 executing
Thread 1 executing
Thread 2 executing
Thread 1 executing
Thread 2 executing
Thread 2 executing
Thread 1 executing
Final value of n is 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Once a `std::tread` is created it is in a running state where it *can* execute instructions.

There is no guarantee that it will do anything at all in any given interval of time, but the probability that it does something goes ever closer to 100% as that interval gets longer and longer.

Usually, design for liveliness practically guarantees that when you get up to intervals of tenths of seconds, all your non-waiting threads will exhibit some activity.